# Project Reactor - combine two Publishers statefuly and emit the result

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'd like to design a processing pipeline with the Reactor that does as follows.

I have two input Publishers `orderEntries` (cold) and `hotBroadcasts` (hot). I'd like to to aggregate items emitted by `hotBroadcasts` into (mutable) inmemory data structure - say a `HashMap` - and for each item from `orderEntries` I'd like to pick an corresponding element from that Map, create resulting item and push to downstream subscriber.

The events from `hotBroadcasts` comes in arbitrary order, that's why I want to store them inmemory for easy retrieval.

Conceptually, it should work like this:

```
       orderEntries                      hotBroadcasts
           |                                   | 
           |                                   | 
           |                                   | 
           \                                   / 
            ----------------> <----------------
                   (aggregate events from hotBroadcasts)     
                             |
                             |
                        resulting item
                             |
                             |
                            \/
                      downstream subcriber
```

So far I managed to sketch a solution with a `ReplayProcessor`, illustrated by the Kotlin pseudo-example:

```
val orderEntries = Flux.interval(Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
val hotBroadcasts = ReplayProcessor.create<String>(1000, false)

orderEntries.concatMap { entryId ->
    // problematic filter - skims through all that ReplayProcessor has cached
    hotBroadcasts.filter { broadcastId ->
        "Broadcast:$entryId" == broadcastId
    }
    .take(1)
    .map { "EntryId: $entryId, BroadcastId: $it" }
}.subscribe { LOG.info(it) }

Flux.interval(Duration.of(200, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
        .concatMap { Flux.just(it, it - 100000) }
        .map { "Broadcast:$it" }
        .subscribe {
            hotBroadcasts.onNext(it)
        }
```

The problem here is that filtering of `hotBroadcast` skims through all items for every item from `orderEntries`. Hence my idea about storing them in the HashMap.

Could anyone point me to correct direction?

Comment: How do you know when you've aggregated everything? Or will you just aggregate until you receive a message on the cold flux? Either way, it seems that that takeWhile is what you want?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just thinking to employ a time window of sort.

Comment: Why not then `window` and `combineLatest`? Your solution looks very over complicated for the stated requirements so what is it that makes your case special?

Comment: Could you please post a code example? I don't think my case is special, I actually think this must be a pretty common problem, but can't really wrap my head around that. Really, what bothers me is the inefficiency of `hotBroadcasts.filter...`, that's it.

Comment: how an orderEntry matches an hotBroadcast? By the order of their creation, or they both has some label which must match?

Comment: The both have a label that must match.

Answer (score -1):

The object which can aggregate messages from two distinct publishers is an asynchronous procedure call with 2 parameters. Such a call can be constructed in rxjava using `io.reactivex.Single.zip(SingleSource arg1, SingleSource arg2, BiFunction func)`, or in pure Java using `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCombine(CompletionStage arg2, BiFunction func)`.

You need a special HashMap which holds that asynchronous procedure calls. The calls should be created automatically when this HashMap is accessed with given label for the first time.

So one Publicher invokes

```
asyncProc=callMap.get(label); // asyncProc is created and stored with the label as a key
asyncProc.arg1.complete(value);
```

and the other Publicher invokes

```
asyncProc=callMap.get(label); // previously created instance returned
asyncProc.arg2.complete(value);
```

After both publishers have supplied their arguments, the asynchronous procedure is executed.